# Input field formats data differently-depending on the type of data inputted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field which is linked to a database that can take either a postcode or a city. the problem is that the postcode needs to be in a certain format i.e.

```
CB30AX
cb30ax
sg120js
SG120JS
```

Capitalization is not really an issue, but must not contain any spaces... With research, I have managed to put together this script below:

```
<script>
//make sure postcode goes in correct format
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('input[name="sCity"]').change(function (){
            var postCode = $(this).val();

            $(this).val(postCode.replace(/\s/g, '').toUpperCase())
        })
    });
</script>
```

Which capitalizes all letters and removes spaces perfectly, however, in the UK there are cities such as: `Leigh On Sea`, `Canvey Island` which have a space, so the code above would make it into one word. How can I made the code detect whether the input is either a city or a postcode (maybe validates a postcode and if returns true it then formats accordingly?
Thanks in advance!

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0zdd6cr3/)

Comment: Only format the input on `blur`/`change`; if there's numbers then assume it's a postcode, otherwise it's a city name. http://jsfiddle.net/0zdd6cr3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there're numbers then assume it's a postcode, otherwise it's a city name.

http://jsfiddle.net/0zdd6cr3/2

```
$('input[name="sCity"]').change(function () {
    var postCode = this.value.toUpperCase();
    if(/\d/.test(postCode)) postCode = postCode.replace(/\s/g, '');
    $(this).val(postCode);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will try this now on live website. What about if I wanted to capitalize the first letter of city? So if someone entered canvey island it would return Canvey Island?

Comment: @ben_dchost - Oh, so you only to capitalize the first letter if it's a city?

Comment: if it's possible I would prefer it, but it's not a must :)

Comment: Thank you so much Derek, you're the best! I really must get round to learning JQuery! :)